# How to make a parent container have its height set to the maximum value between a fixed px height and child content height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, grid

How can I have a parent container meets the following conditions:

1. has a max-height of 80vh
2. has a height that is the maximum between: a) 400px (or any fixed height) b) height of child contents
3. child contents cannot extend past parent container
4. when the child contents grow, they keep growing until it hits the parent's max height of 80% (and then it scrolls)

I already have logic for 1, 3 and 4. but im not sure about how to implement the second condition. Here is some sample code i wrote:

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border: solid 5px black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child {
  border: solid 5px red;
  width: auto;
  height: 550px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think I am looking for something like height: max(400px, max-content). But is this possible/how would I implement this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: afak there is no OR option in css rules, have you played with min-content and max-content? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content

Comment: yeah, i meant i want the parent height to be the max of (400px, max-content). but i dont think we can use max-content like that, so im wondering if there's some other way to implement the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height):

> max-height overrides height, but min-height overrides max-height.

So to make sure your condition 1 is always definitely met (maximum height of 80vh) you not only have to set max-height to that but you have to make sure that if 400px is greater than 80vh that the height does not go above 80vh, otherwise it will go to 400px and overrule the max height of 80vh.

```
max-height: 80vh;
min-height: min(400px, 80vh);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you delete the height of parent, the parent going to take the height from child but no more for `80vh` that is the max height for parent, so if the child height is more than `80vh` the parent get scroll for the rest height child.

Comment: sorry, i mean that i want the parent container to be 400px when the child content height is any height between 0px to 400px. So i want the parent container have a height of 400px at a minimum, except when 400px becomes larger than 80vh (which could happen if we zoom in the browser)

Comment: change height: 400px; for min-height : 400px; in the parent

Comment: except when 400px becomes larger than 80vh (which could happen if we zoom in the browser). i think in this case better use responsive CSS for that case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).